# unexepted @ in program

Tags: xcode

I've created a UIViewController class with a XIB Attached. Without adding anything, the compiler tells me "UNEXEPTED @ IN PROGRAM" on the .h file at the @interface line and repeat the same error on the @end line

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface iPegasoDatiCorpoCli : UIViewController

-(id)initWithStrings:(NSString *)lblcorpo1 :(NSString *)lblcorpo2 :(NSString *)lblcorpo3 :(NSString *)<nibNameOrNil :(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;

@end
```

This class is implemented to create a custo cell view and it worked till now. I've created also a new class just like this one but never used it and still gaves me the same error 3 Builds every 5. It's giving me headache

Comment: Are you compiling as C or Objective C ? What is the file that has i=the include or import (and which of those)?

Comment: `initWithStrings:::::` is probably the worst method signature I saw in the last 60 minutes.

Comment: It's compiled in Objective C. I've tried to remove the initWithStrings method and leaved the plain .h File but the error is still on it. The Declaration is to create a custom Collection View cell and the header is implemented in a plain .m file (It now contains only the standard Overwritten method of the UIViewController class)

Answer (score 1):

There is typo, extra **>** symbol in  please check:

```
-(id)initWithStrings:(NSString *)lblcorpo1 :(NSString *)lblcorpo2 :(NSString *)lblcorpo3 :(NSString *)<nibNameOrNil :(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;
-----                                                                                                 ^
```

EDIT:

Why you are passing 6-7 arguments to a method. Wrap them in a class or pass an array of strings.

Comment: Fixed the typo and tried also to remove the method. Nothing worked. I've created this method just as a reminder, i was just thinking of passing them to an Array, but this problem has locked my work since it's first appearing

Comment: if you can send the code, mail me or post in some online drives

Comment: Did you fix the method signature in both the header and the implementation?

Comment: Fixed the signature in both. Nothing. I'm starting to think x-code hates me. It randomly gaves me error on NSObject class.

OK, one class is now working fine. The other one still got the same problems

Comment: EDIT- The problem is suddenly reappeared in both class.